# is making functions 'independent' best practice in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to programming in C and I'm trying to learn the best ways of writing code cleanly. I'm trying to write my functions so they can be reused in other programs without rewriting other parts of the code.

I wrote a function which takes a value from an ADC, processes it and returns two bytes of output data for a DAC. Since this returns two data I either have to return a struct or an array, but both of these methods seem to involve using global variables meaning my functions don't function independently.

I could also include an input to the function which tells it whether to return the upper or lower byte, but it seems like a waste to have to run it twice.

What is common practice in a situation like this? Am I right to try and make my functions independent?

Comment: Why don't you add a parameter with a pointer to a struct containing the returned data? The caller will be in charge to provide a valid (allocated) pointer to that struct. No global variables (not necessarily).

Comment: You can return a struct or write to a given array/struct without using global variables.

Comment: "Returning upper and lower bytes sound like "returning a 16 bit value". Is this an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) ?

Comment: Sure. An reusable function is a best practice to save design time and memory space. But if a service function needs some dedicated data structure, it is common to have a accompanying header file (.h file) which defines the data structure and declare the function (extern ... func(...);). Then the user of the function merely include the .h file and allocate the data structure needed to call the service.

Comment: `int/*status*/ ADC2DAC(int input, int *out1, int *out2) { if (input < 0) return 1; if (input > 65535) return 2; *out1 = input & 0xff; *out2 = (input >> 8) & 0xff; return 0; }`

Comment: Your function is still dependent on the ADC. It needs its *address* , and also its *type* (or: protocol)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Independent" and "code re-use" are different, unrelated things.

For example, it is a 100% good thing to make your ADC driver independent and unaware of the UART driver, because it doesn't make sense to have these two drivers communicate with each other directly. If you wish to read something from the ADC and print the result on UART, you'd have a 3rd, higher layer module which accesses each driver and passes on the ADC results to the UART.

That is also what you should do when passing on results from an ADC to a DAC. This is aligned with various widely recognized good design philosophies such as *private encapsulation* and *loose coupling*.

So you should have something like this:

```
// main.c

#include "adc.h"   // ADC driver
#include "dac.h"   // DAC driver

...

uint16_t adc_result;
uint8_t  dac_data[2];

adc_result = adc_read();
serialize(adc_result, dac_data);
dac_write(dac_data);
```

Where `serialize` could be a local function in the caller or placed in a module of its own (if it's complex enough to merit that). I don't know what exactly this function should do, but it sounds very specialized and therefore it is unlikely to hold any value for some other piece of the code. It could perhaps look something like:

```
static void serialize (uint16_t input, uint8_t output[2])
{
   output[0] = (input >> 8) & 0xFF;  // read MS byte
   output[1] = input & 0xFF;         // read LS byte
}
```

Where `static` means that the function is local to the file it is placed in.

Note the complete absence of global variables in this code. `adc_read()` is likely a "getter" function that returns an internal `static` file scope variable.

Answer (score 4):

> Since this returns two data I either have to return a struct or an array, but both of these methods seem to involve using global variables

I do not see how that's related. Just return the structure.

```
struct two_data {
     int one_data;
     int second_data;
};

struct two_data function_that_returns_two_data(void) {
    struct two_data return_me = { 1, 2 };
    return return_me;
}
```

It's not possible to return an array type from a function. To return an array, create a structure to return it.

Still you could just set the values via pointers:

```
void function_that_returns_two_data(int *dataone, int *datatwo) {
     *dataone = 6;
     *datatwo = 5;
}
int main() {
    int dataone, datatwo;
    function_that_returns_two_data(&dataone, &datatwo);
}
```

and do similar with passing the structure via a pointer, preferably reserving the return value for error detection.

> What is common practice in a situation like this?

Standard POSIX functions like [clock_get*](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getres.2.html) return two values in `struct timespec` - number of seconds and number of nanoseconds. They take `timespec` via a pointer and indicate error via return value (as all standard functions they use "global" variable `errno` for error recognition - don't use it and use return value itself to transfer error code). Newer functions like [pthread_getattr_np](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_getattr_np.3.html) and many other POSIX functions - they return error number in return value and do not use errno.

Comment: A POSIX OS sounds rather unlikely to co-exist with ADC/DAC low level hardware. The computer might not even have a RTC for all we know.

Answer (score 1):

Pass your struct or array as an argument to the function and have the function modify it (using an array for this example):

```
void get_bytes( unsigned char *bytes )
{
  bytes[0] = ...;
  bytes[1] = ...;
}

int main( void )
{
  unsigned char b[2];
  ...
  get_bytes( b );
  do_something_with( b );
  ...
}
```

If it makes your code flow more easily (such as if you need to pass the result of `get_bytes` to another function), you can return the input argument:

```
unsigned char *get_bytes( unsigned char *bytes )
{
  bytes[0] = ...;
  bytes[1] = ...;
  return bytes;
}

...
do_something_with( get_bytes( b ) );
...
```

Similar, but with a struct:

```
struct bytes { unsigned char lo, hi };

struct bytes get_bytes( struct bytes *bytes )
{
  bytes->lo = ...;
  bytes->hi = ...;
  return *bytes;
}

int main( void )
{
  struct bytes b;
  ...
  get_bytes( &b );
  do_something_with( b );
  ...
}
```

Like above, you can collapse that to:

```
do_something_with( get_bytes( &b ) );
```

You’ll notice I don’t use the `&` operator with the array version.  Under most circumstances, expressions of array type “decay” to pointer types, so when you pass an array expression as a function argument, what the function actually receives is a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm new to programming in C and I'm trying to learn the best ways of writing code cleanly. I'm trying to write my functions so they can be reused in other programs without rewriting other parts of the code.

Reusability is almost always the preferred way to write code, but don't give yourself a headache, but if you have a specific function for a specific program and it's going to be rarely used in another one, then try to make it reusable at least to that program, sometimes you have to code specific pieces of code.

> I wrote a function which takes a value from an ADC, processes it and returns two bytes of output data for a DAC. Since this returns two data I either have to return a struct or an array, but both of these methods seem to involve using global variables meaning my functions don't function independently.

You don't need to use global variables, you can return a pointer to a struct or an array with both values. Otherwise you return nothing from the function and use function arguments, passing two pointers to two different bytes, or a pointer to an array or a pointer to a struct to save the bytes there.

> I could also include an input to the function which tells it whether to return the upper or lower byte, but it seems like a waste to have to run it twice.

Already answered. You don't need to run it twice. But you could.

> What is common practice in a situation like this? Am I right to try and make my functions independent?

Already answered.